# count the number of sequential duplicates in excel but start back at 1 if there are more than 3 sequential duplicates

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have a spreadsheet displaying hardware equipment in sector level. For instance:

```
023008_SHELBY
023008_SHELBY
023008_SHELBY
023009_SWAN_29TH_ST
023009_SWAN_29TH_ST
023009_SWAN_29TH_ST
023010_BUTTERFIELD
023010_BUTTERFIELD
023010_BUTTERFIELD
023010_BUTTERFIELD
023010_BUTTERFIELD
023010_BUTTERFIELD
023011_PARK_LOWELL_OPERA
023011_PARK_LOWELL_OPERA
023011_PARK_LOWELL_OPERA
```

What I want to do is count the number of sequential duplicates but max it out at 3. In other words, the list above shows butterfield 6 times. On the 4th count I want it to start back at 1 instead 4 and so on. I know using formula =IF(A2=A1,B1+1,1) will count these duplicates but not limit it to 3. Is there any way to do this? Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`=IF(A2=A1,MOD(B1,3)+1,1)`

`MOD` is the [modulo operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) that will find the remainder after dividing by, in this case, 3.